# ERROR sudo pecl install mongodb on Linux apache

Tags: php, linux, mongodb

I'm trying to install mongodb for php 7.4:

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

But i'm getting this error in the linux console.

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 249
> PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command.php on line 249
> .....
>
> XML Extension not found

Comment: Looks like you may need to install the PHP XML extension.

Comment: Thanks, that worked: sudo apt-get install php7.4-xml, and sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the xml extension was not enabled.

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-xml
```

and restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```